# css image overlay issues on browser resize

Tags: css, image, layout, resize, overlay

i have a problem with my css layout. I have designed it with my resolution (1920x1080px) and it looks right. but if i resize the browser to simulate a smaller screen resolution i got a problem with my background images I cant handle to fix.
You can see my layout here:

http://www.lolers.de/design/

As you can see the corner images overlay the content.

I tried another layout technique with z-indexes which you can see here:

http://www.lolers.de/design/alternative/

but it overlays the top corner images which doesnt look good.

I already tried around for ours but cant get a solution. 
Or is it possible to do such a background with css 3 features like canvas?

greets

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of how you want it to look like?

Comment: Why don't you just use 1 background image?

Comment: Are box-shadow or border-image not an option?

Comment: It may not be an option, but "somehow" similar effect may be achieved using radial-gradient and box-shadow - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juicyscripter/z54Hq/4/embedded/result/)  (you'll need to tweak the colors and dimensions which may be not that easy to get exactly same result)

Comment: i already tried it with box-shadow which works with opera, safari, firefox etc. but our lovely internet explorer doenst support it. Also one background-image wouldnt be resolution dynamic

Comment: Does it matter?  Will an IE user be able to tell that the content in question has broken styling?  Give IE an attractive fallback and move forward.

Comment: well cimmanon thats what i actually did now. After ive been thinking I just set up a message for ie users that the page isnt supported with ie. i mean why should we actually support the worst browser ever. already wasted half of a day because of it.